# How to write a pyvista PolyData to stream or in-memory Buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, vtk, pyvista

The overall construct is an FastAPI Webserver to which a GemPy Model is send. This is then plotted as a 3D Model. From this I can extract the Layers as PyVista/VTK PolyData Objects. Until this point is works fine, however these Objects should idealy send back to the client as a useable file which isn´t just practicle in PYthon (e.g. .glb/.vtk/.ply). I know technically how to do that, however for the Server side i tried to save the file into a buffer, which seems impossible to implement with pyvista.PolyData.save() or vtk.vtkWriter.

My Code looks like this

```
# this just creates an object from which the layers can be extracted as polydata
gpv = gp.plot_3d(geo_model)

# here an examples how to get polydata or an unstructuredgrid
poly = gpv.surface_poly['Sandstone_2']

grid = pv.UnstructuredGrid(poly)
```

from this i´d like to ether save it with pyvista

```
poly.save("filename.ply")
```

or alternativley with vtk

```
def write_grid_to_vtk(grid, filename):

    writer = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridWriter()
    writer.SetFileName(filename)
    writer.SetInputData(grid)
    #writer.SetFileTypeToBinary()
    writer.Write()

buf = io.BytesIO()
write_grid_to_vtk(grid, buf)
buf.close()
```

in the vtk example you can see, how i tried to implement the buffer. This Throws an `TypeError: SetFileName argument %Id: %V`

Does anyone know how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is serialization. PyVista meshes already support serialization via the pickle protocol, which would be as simple as `pickle.dumps(poly)` and on the other side `pickle.loads(b)`. But `pickle` is known to be insecure against malicious pickle files, so you might want to avoid exposing your users to that mechanics.

Instead you can [look at how PyVista implements the `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` methods used for pickling](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/blob/5d7fbf982202f62aa2164dcac702319dcd12cf12/pyvista/core/dataobject.py#L516-L612) (in particular the newer, `'xml'` code path).

Here's a stripped-down example geared at `PolyData`:

```py
import pyvista as pv
from vtkmodules.vtkIOXML import vtkXMLPolyDataReader, vtkXMLPolyDataWriter

def poly_to_bytes(mesh):
    """Serialize a PolyData to bytes."""
    writer = vtkXMLPolyDataWriter()
    writer.SetInputDataObject(mesh)
    writer.SetWriteToOutputString(True)
    writer.SetDataModeToBinary()
    writer.SetCompressorTypeToNone()
    # or perhaps SetCompressorTypeToZLib() etc.
    writer.Write()
    return writer.GetOutputString()

def bytes_to_poly(bs):
    """Unserialize a bytes to pyvista.PolyData."""
    reader = vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
    reader.ReadFromInputStringOn()
    reader.SetInputString(bs)
    reader.Update()
    return pv.wrap(reader.GetOutput())

# example polydata
poly = pv.Dodecahedron()

# serialize
bs = poly_to_bytes(poly)
# ... imagine sending this to the client

# unserialize
poly_after = bytes_to_poly(bs)

print(poly == poly_after)  # True
```

You can also choose from a handful of compressors, the options can be found in the documentation of [`vtkXMLWriterBase`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLWriterBase.html#a7ded58a9a13e453833e6f9d1bdd94329). I tried the `None` and `ZLib` cases in the above snippet, and compression takes down the bytestring from 3376 bytes to 2699 bytes. You'll want to consider the tradeoff between compression time/effort and reduced network traffic.